# Help translating とってもまずしくて明日食べるパンもありません

Tags: translation, syntax, relative-clauses

The sentence is

> とってもまずしくて明日食べるパンもありません。

I know all of the words, but the grammar is confusing. Why is *ashita taberu* in the middle of the sentence?

Comment: 明日食べるパン===bread (I) eat tomorrow
It just works like that. Not really sure how to explain it too well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「とってもまずしくて**明日食べるパン**もありません。」

＝

> 「とってもまずしくて、**明日食べるパン**もありません。」

「[明日食]{あしたた}べる」 is a relative clause that modifies 「パン」.  In the Japanese word order, the relative clause is placed in front of the noun that you want to give additional information to.

In English, needless to say, it is the other way around -- "the bread that I (can) eat tomorrow".  "Bread" comes first.

> "(Someone) is so poor that he does not even have any bread to eat tomorrow."

Without more context, one could not tell who the subject is.  It could be "I", the speaker himself.

Some examples:

「7-11で[買]{か}ったコーラ」 = "the cola that I bought at 7-11"

「ニューヨークにあるレストラン」 = "a/the restaurant that is in New York"

「ネットで[見]{み}たかわいいネコ」 = "the cute cat that I saw on the internet"